# Finding good Mbtiles to png tiles converter?

Tags: convert, tiles, png, mbtiles

I'm trying to create a slippy map and I need to obtain png tiles. I have exported a .mbtiles file from TileMill and I tried several python scripts to convert this file into png tiles but I always end up with a messy folder where the tiles are misnamed, and I can't use them into my app.

Does anyone know a good converter which organize and name your tiles properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) by authors of MBTiles format. Usage is explained on that page.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you for your fast answer.

Comment: the png format option generate a peculiar gzip files. How to turn it to regular png?